# verifyLevel function is not working as I want, all levels are seeing my page content

Tags: php

Im trying to do a verify level function to use on top of my pages, to control access to each page depending on the level of administrator.

I did this function now for this purpose:

```
function verifyLevel($userId){      
    $pdo = start();
    $read = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM admins where id = :userId");  
    $read->bindValue(":userId", $userId);  
    $read->execute();
    $result = $read->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    echo $result['level'];  
}
```

And now Im trying to use this function.

Admins have level 1, 2 or 3.

In this page, I want to allow that users with level 1 and 3 can see the content.

Only admins with level 2 can´t see content of this page and I want to show a message saying that they dont have permissions to admins with level 2.

Im trying like this:

```
if(function_exists('verifyLevel')){
    if(verifyLevel($_SESSION['admin']['id'] == '2')){

        echo 'Sorry, but you dont have permissions to acess this page.';
    }
    else{
        //I show page content

   }
}
```

But its not working, all levels are having acess to content of this page.

Do you see where is my error?

Comment: `$_SESSION['admin']['id'] == '2'` is boolean and you're passing that, so it'll be 0 or 1.  Probably not your intention?

Comment: And after what @scrowler said, prob change the conditional to `if(verifyLevel($_SESSION['admin']['id']) == '2'){`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're echoing the result from `verifyLevel()`, you need to return it for it to be comparable:

```
function verifyLevel($userId){      
    // ...
    return $result['level'];  
}

// bracket in wrong place   -----------V--not--v
if(verifyLevel($_SESSION['admin']['id']) == '2') {
    echo 'Sorry, but you dont have permissions to acess this page.';
}
```

[As mentioned by Jeremy Miller,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24815856/verifylevel-function-is-not-working-as-i-want-all-levels-are-seeing-my-page-con/24815880#comment-38522850) the way you had your function call set up, it would be passing in a boolean of either true or false, which is loosely equivalent to 0 or 1, so your user would probably not be returned correctly from the database either:

```
// incorrect comparison here, passing boolean instead (0 or 1)
var_dump(verifyLevel($_SESSION['admin']['id'] == '2'));
```

Should be:

```
// true representation of your function's processing and comparison
var_dump(verifyLevel($_SESSION['admin']['id']) == '2');
// verifyLevel($_SESSION['admin']['id']) will either be 1, 2 or 3
```